# How to log result if shell command from systemd service?

Tags: systemd, raspbian

I have this service that starts mysqlwifi.js using nodejs

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/mysqlwifi.service;

 [Unit]
 Description=MySQL exampledb update
 After=multi-user.target
 After=network-online.target
 Wants=network-online.target

 [Service]
 Type=idle
 Restart=always
 RestartSec=6
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/dietpi/node_server/mysqlwifi.js > /home/dietpi/node_server/mysqlwifi.log 2>&1

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If i run node /home/dietpi/node_server/mysqlwifi.js directly in terminal i do see output in shell

Comment: The output is being redirected to `/home/dietpi/node_server/mysqlwifi.log`. Isn't that enough?

Comment: The log file is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you are trying to use shell redicets in `systemd`'s `ExecStart=` statement. This shell behavior is not directly transferable to a `systemd` service unit.

---

**Option 1**: write it all in a shell script and change executed command:

```
 #my_script
 #!/bin/bash
 /usr/bin/node /path/to/script.js  >>/path/to/logfile 2>&1
```

and use `StartExec=/path/to/my_script.sh` (set executable bit).

---

**Option 2**: use the following in the unit file to manually redirect streams ([Reference](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)):

```
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /path/to/script.js
 StandardOutput=file:/path/to/logfile
 StandardError=file:/path/to/logfile
```

Use `StardardOutput=append:/path/to/logfile` to append rather than overwrite the file (same for `StandardError`) as stated in the above reference.

---

**Option 3**: use `systemd`'s own logservice `systemd-journald`

```
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=mysqlwifi
```

**Note**: Setting those three is actually not necessary, as using `syslog` for `stdout` and `stderr` as well as using the unit name as identifier is standard behavior - this is merely for the sake of clarity.

Maybe set `Storage=persistent` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` to enable logs being written to disk storage instead of memory and thus have permanent records. (Check for disk usage or set limits in the conf-file via `SystemMaxFileSize=` & co. More details [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html#))

Call logs via `journalctl -u mysqlwifi`.

Comment: this is not rotational, and `StandardOutput ` overwrite the file each time.

Comment: the option 1 logging is not working just end up an empty log file, option 2 only error stack trace gets outputs in `StandardOutput`

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz See changes to `1`: switched redirection ([ref](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553471/how-do-i-really-hide-all-console-output-from-the-process-i-start/553474#comment1027923_553474)) and added appending mode for the redirect. Changes to `2`: Change to `append:` to use appending mode. If you want to enable logrotation, modify your `/etc/logrotate.conf` and/or add an entry in `/etc/logrotate.d` - but this is a fully different topic.

Comment: When you are adding `append` you are not giving it file identfier ?

Comment: i discovered my ubuntu bionic beaver does not have support for `append`.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz You do use the identifiyer: `append:/path/to/logfile` as stated in the answer. If you do not have append, try the following `StandardOutput=/path/to/logfile` --- `StandardError=inherit`  and then copy the file after stopping the service with a `ExecStop=` script.