# How do I really hide all console output from the process I start?

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

I was getting all those messages from firefox that I didn't care about:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

So I killed `firefox` and restarted it like this:

```
$ firefox 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

As in "redirect `stderr` into `stdout` and pipe both of them out into the `null`".

Unfortunately, those pesky messages didn't disappear. In fact, the terminal window where I started the `firefox` session into which I am currently typing this question is still producing them.

So the questions are:

Why the above redirection didn't work?

How do I redirect them correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it in the opposite order: first redirect stdout, then redirect stderr to stdout:

```
firefox >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

EDIT: Here's an explanation. `2>&1` is a file-descriptor duplication operation (see the bash man page and search for `Duplicating File Descriptors`): it says "duplicate file descriptor 2 to do the same thing as file descriptor 1". Afterwards, anything written to fd 2 will be sent to wherever fd 1 sends things. So stderr (2) and stdout (1) will write to the same place. But they are independent, so if you change fd 1 afterwards (e.g. by redirecting stdout), fd 2 will stay put: it will still write to wherever fd 1 was writing *before* that last redirection.

If you redirect stdout first and then duplicate, then both fd 1 and fd 2 are writing to the same place: wherever fd 1 was redirected to.

Basically, the shell executes redirections/duplications from left to right, so you have to get the order right.

Note by the way that, as a special case, bash provides a shortcut for redirecting both stdout and stderr to the same place:

```
 cmd &> /dev/null
```

is equivalent to

```
  cmd > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.

Comment: Could you explain the reason for this? This seems very non-intuitive to me.

Comment: Added an explanation - hope it helps.